# Constrain height of image wrapped in <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive layout that requires my image heights be constrained to the available window height (minus header). It works fine with just images in a <div>, but if the images are wrapped in an <a> tag the height is no longer constrained. Resizing the browser no longer has an effect on the image, even as it properly sizes the <a>.

How do I constrain the image height within the <a> tag so it doesn't just overflow? I'm using the jquery cycle2 plugin, so a CSS-only solution is strongly preferred to avoid conflicts.

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 body {
  background-color: #CCC;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 header {
  background-color: white;
  height: 4.5em;
 }
 #content {
  height: calc(100% - 72px);
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #inner-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
 } 
 .ps-slideshow-container {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .cycle-slideshow {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 72px);
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
 } 
 .cycle-slideshow a {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
 }
 .cycle-slideshow a img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc(100% - 36px);
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 .ps-cycle-meta {
  background-color: #999;
 }
 .wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
 <div id="inner-header" class="wrap">Resize does not work</div>
</header>
<div id="content">
 <div id="inner-content" class="wrap">
  <div class="ps-slideshow-container">
   <div class="cycle-slideshow">
       <a href="" class="cycle-slide"><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" alt="image1"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="ps-cycle-nav-1" class="ps-cycle-nav ps-centered"><a href="" class="ps-pro-genericon ps-pro-genericon-previous">Prev</a><a href="" class="ps-pro-genericon ps-pro-genericon-next">Next</a></div>
   <div id="alt-caption" class="center ps-cycle-meta">Caption</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Working JSFiddle (just <img>)](https://jsfiddle.net/arno_afterlung/t77juLoe/)

[Non-working JSFiddle (<a><img></a>)](https://jsfiddle.net/arno_afterlung/u17h0hec/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.cycle-slideshow a {
    display: block
}
```

you can't define a max-height for inline-block in this case.

Comment: I've edited the snippets and JSFiddle to remove the inline-block. It didn't need to be there, but it's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a `height:auto` property to your link, his height will takes the height of the image inside. So remove this property and set it a height to 100% to fill the container.

```
.cycle-slideshow a {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```